# I'm pulling the data from the api, then I get an error when I delete and post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

https://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Patient I want to do a get post and delete operation with axios from this api. While performing the get operation successfully, I am getting errors in the delete and post operation.Actually, I think I've solved some of the problem, because the api I got is not an object, I'm getting these errors probably, but I don't know how to convert an api to an object or I don't have the slightest idea how to use the object function, please help me

```jsx
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Patient",
});

const App = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [body, setBody] = useState("");
  const [patients, setPosts] = useState([]);

  // GET with Axios
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPost = async () => {
      try {
        let response = await client.get("?_limit=10");
        setPosts(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchPost();
  }, []);

  // DELETE with Axios
  const deletePost = async (id) => {
    try {
      await client.delete(`${id}`);
      setPosts(
        patients.filter((post) => {
          return post.id !== id;
        })
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // handle form submission
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addPosts(title, body);
  };

  // POST with Axios
  const addPosts = async (title, body) => {
    try {
      let response = await client.post("", {
        title: title,
        body: body,
      });
      setPosts([response.data, ...patients]);
      setTitle("");
      setBody("");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <nav>
        <h1>POSTS APP</h1>
      </nav>
      <div className="add-post-container">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            value={title}
            onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
          />
          <textarea
            name=""
            className="form-control"
            id=""
            cols="10"
            rows="8"
            value={body}
            onChange={(e) => setBody(e.target.value)}
          ></textarea>
          <button type="submit">Add Post</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className="patients-container">
        <h2>All Posts </h2>
        {patients?.entry?.map((patient) => (
          <div className="patient-card" key={patient.id}>
            {patient?.resource?.address?.map((adr) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <p>{adr.city}</p>
                  <p>{adr.postalCode}</p>
                </>
              );
            })}
            <div className="button">
              <button
                className="delete-btn"
                onClick={() => deletePost(patient.id)}
              >
                Delete
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is the error I get while doing the delete operation: TypeError: patients.filter is not a function at deletePost (Patient.js:31:1) This is the error I get while doing the add operation POST hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Patient 400 (Bad Request) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST' –

Comment: What kind of error(s) do you get when you run the DELETE and POST requests?

Comment: As Kostas mentioned, the first thing we should focus is what kind of http error is logged in console.  The first thing that comes to mind is permissions for post and delete operations in the server. Proper headers and authentication might be your need (anyhow, the http error code in your console could give us a hint).

Comment: This is the error I get while doing the delete operation:

TypeError: patients.filter is not a function
    at deletePost (Patient.js:31:1) 

This is the error I get while doing the add operation

POST https://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Patient 400 (Bad Request)

AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST'

Comment: Random but did you try adding a / before the id? so --  client.delete('/${id}') -- right now the url would added something like /Patient9999 instead of /Patient/9999

Comment: A 400 response means your request payload is invalid. Have you tried looking at the response, either in your dev-tools _Network_ panel or simply adding `console.error(err.response?.data)`. It's probably telling you what's wrong

Comment: There's some obvious problems here... the API response is not an array so when you call `setPosts(response.data)`, the `patients` is no longer an array and `filter` won't work. When trying out the POST request, I get an error back... _"HAPI-1838: Invalid JSON content detected, missing required element: 'resourceType'"_